# Create a record in Rails from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have an Angular application that sends http requests to a rails server. I'd like to make a request to create a record (in the table SavedQueries).

The Angular app is actually making a very simple http request right now, like

```
$.post('http://10.241.16.159:3000/api/save_query', {'saved_query':1});
```

That javascript request gets routed to this Rails action:

```
def create
  @saved_query = SavedQuery.new(params[:saved_query])

  if @saved_query.save
    render json: @saved_query, status: :created, location: @saved_query
  else
    render json: @saved_query.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

However, instead of returning the appropriate json, the rails server logs a 500 error:

```
Started POST "/api/save_query" for 172.25.82.146 at 2014-07-31 19:14:06 +0000
Processing by SavedQueriesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"saved_query"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
  app/controllers/saved_queries_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

So my question is, clearly by looking at the logs from the Rails server, we can see that the params passed was a hash, but the ArgumentError thrown says that the problem was that a hash must be passed as an argument.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving these parameters:

```
Parameters: {"saved_query"=>"1"}
```

ie, `params[:saved_query]` returns `"1"`. Thus, when you do

```
@saved_query = SavedQuery.new(params[:saved_query])
```

you are really doing

```
@saved_query = SavedQuery.new("1")
```

and that's not going to work, as `SavedQuery.new` expects a `Hash`, not a `String`.

If instead you do

```
@saved_query = SavedQuery.new(params)
```

it should work.

Comment: Awesome! although now I'm getting "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError"

Comment: You're now running into Rails' [strong parameters](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html). You should be able to find some explanations googling for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@saved_query = SavedQuery.new(params[:saved_query])
```

Your `.new` on `SavedQuery` is essentially calling `SavedQuery.new("1")`, and Rails is having a problem with the value not having a key.

`SavedQuery.new() #=> if no values are required`

`SavedQuery.new(age:1) #=> if there is an int column within the SavedQuery model, for example`